# I need to change the name of an text documente through a cicle

Tags: python-2.7

I need that this code create text documents but i need that the name change every time i create a new text document, an example will be that when execute the code it will create a text document named " aventura-1.txt " then why execute again and the name will be " aventura-2.txt" so on too " aventura-n.txt" How i can do that.?

sorry for my bad english btw, this is the code which i have.

```
  import os
  def adventure_path ( nombre_aventura) :
    if not os. path . isdir (" aventuras ") :
     os. mkdir (" aventuras ")
    return " aventuras/ %s" %nombre_aventura
  archivo = open ( adventure_path ("aventura-n.txt") ,"w")
  print "hi"
  print "bye"
  archivo . close ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code that I wrote once and tweaked a little for you...

It will:

1. `check` each file in a specific folder
2. `split` the names of these files at `"."` and `"-"`, so we'll be able to catch only the number part of your `.txt` name *(i'm assuming you'll have a specific folder that contains ONLY "aventura-n.txt" named like files)*
3. `add` this number to a list
4. `get` the `max` value of the numbers list
5. `add +1` to get the next version number

**Code:**

```
import os

nums = []

for item in os.listdir('path_to_folder'):
    a = item.split(".")[0]
    b = a.split("-")[1]
    c = int(b)
    nums.append(c)

next_num = max(nums) + 1
print next_num
```